# How can I turn a pandas interval into a legend-friendly string?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas.cut returns one or several intervals. I want to use that information to create label-friendly strings. My goal is to from iv in the code, get this string: "20-35 %".

```
iv=pd.Interval(left=0.2, right=0.35)
```

I've tried this so far, but it doesn't, to me at least, seem like an optimal solution. Further on  this information will be used in a plot legend. So I also want to get the categories into the right order in some automated fashion.

```
iv=pd.Interval(left=0.2, right=0.35)
iv=iv*100
a=str(iv)
b=str(iv).replace('(', '').replace(']', '').replace(',', '-').replace(' ', '')
c=b + ' %'
```

Comment: Does not _labels_ argument in cut help?

Comment: The thing is I'm doing an automated report . And different plots will have different number of bins, depending on the diff between min and max values.  So I want to set the labels in an automated fashion as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could leverage `Interval` variables and use as starting point

```
f"{iv.left*100}-{iv.right*100}%"
```

or (formatted) variations of it maybe:

```
f"{(iv.left*100):.0f}-{(iv.right*100):.0f}%"
```